# Inverter switches to fault when sun emerges from cloud

Tags: solar, inverter

My solar setup consists of 3x270 watt panels, a charge controller, a battery and an inverter. It has mostly worked fine for many years, but I've found that the inverter faults when the sun comes out from behind a cloud. If I reset the inverter then it's fine, even in full sunshine, so it seems it's the transition itself from cloudy to sunny, not too much power, that causes a surge of power that the inverter can't handle. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Would check all connections making sure they are clean and tight.  Could also be a sensor/breaker is too touchy, but imagine that will require a electronic repair shop to fix/find.

Comment: Have you contacted the manufacturer of the inverter or even read its manual to see what it lists as the causes of this fault?

Comment: What make and model is your inverter, even?

Comment: The inverter is a very cheap ($70) 1500 watt generic Chinese (Solar Max) inverter widely available here in Nairobi and the manual has basically no information. I actually had another cheap inverter that I used for years until it recently died, but from the beginning it also had the same problem with cloud -> sun transitions.